# .htaccess URL structure with variables stops working w/ pagination

Tags: .htaccess, pagination, url-rewriting

I have a problem with htaccess on one of these 2 pages: **index.php** & **search.php**

Both pages are functional & dependent on variables being sent to them via "GET" method.

---

**SEARCH Example -**

`search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE`

**Showing as:** `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE`

```
# HTACCESS:
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/?$ /search.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]

# internal forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tag/(.+?)/?$ /search.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+search\.php\?tag=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1? [R=302,L]
```

---

**INDEX Example -**

`index.php?id=ID&title=TITLE`

**Showing as:** `site.com/cover/TITLE-ID`

```
# HTACCESS:  
RewriteRule ^cover/(.*)-(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [NC,L]

# internal forward FOR SINGLE PAGE (index)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cover/(.+?)-(.+?)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?id=([^\s]+)&title=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cover/%2-%1? [R=302,L]
```

---

Both pages also have pagination, my problem is, it only works for **search.php**

**SEARCH page** w/ pagination:
`site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE&page=#` ***WORKS! Correct paginated results being returned.***

**INDEX page** w/ pagination:
`site.com/title&page=#-ID` ***Inserts `&page=#` in between the title & ID in the URL, but shows results.***

---

The only difference I see between these 2 are the number of variables being passed on, otherwise they are being rewritten exactly the same.

I need help with making my .htaccess structure work seamlessly w/ pagination query strings for my **index.php** page URL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `QSA` flag in your internal rewrite rules and rearrange your rules.

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cover/%2-%1/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&title=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /cover/%2-%1? [R=302,L]

# external rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?tag=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?tag=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward FOR SINGLE PAGE (index)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cover/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&title=$1&page=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cover/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^tag/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /search.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: What happened with this was it removed the pagination's query altogether, e.g. `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE&page=2` simply led back to `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE`. I couldn't navigate.

Comment: Why pagination URL is `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE&page=2` instead of `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE?page=2`?

Comment: That is where `site.com/search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE` leads to using the .htaccess structure posted in my original post.

Comment: check updated rule. Make sure these are the only rules you have. And then try this URL: `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE/2`

Comment: The latest update is working for search page: `site.com/search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE&page=2` leads to `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE/2`, but it doesn't work for the index page: `site.com/index.php?id=ID&title=TITLE&page=2` just leads back to `site.com/cover/TITLE-ID` stripping the pagination query string off... I've cleared cache before testing.

Comment: Updated: the URL now works for the index page, as well. However, it doesn't show the correct results (the previous update didn't either). `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE/2` is only showing the same results as `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE`... And if you click on PAGE 3, it simply appends the pagination variable to the current URL, e.g. URL now becomes `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE/2/3`, but still shows the same results as the original page.

Comment: `site.com/tag/KEYPHRASE/2` internally becomes `site.com/search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE&page=2` is that not correct? To test comment out `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search\.php\?tag=([^&\s]+)&page=([^&\s]+) [NC]` rule.

Comment: Update: Commented out specified rule, & it triggers a redirect loop on the webpage. Couldn't load the page & got this message instead "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: Not that just that line you needed to comment `RewriteRule ^ /tag/%1/%2? [R=302,L]` as well.

Comment: Update: When both lines commented out - page navigation's URL leads to `site.com/search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE&page=2`, URL shows as is (no rewriting), & results are as desired.

Comment: Update: I didn't realize that I've left the first 2 rewrite rules in (please refer to original post, e.g. `#RewriteRule ^tag/(.*)/?$ /search.php?tag=$1 [NC,L]` and `RewriteRule ^cover/(.*)-(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [NC,L]`). Removing these 2, I realized that the search page works internally & the URL is the expected structure as well. No problems w/ navigation, the variables do not append.

However, removing the above-mentioned rewrite rule for our index didn't make it work, instead the page doesn't work at all. But, leaving it in would have the same behavior as the last update.

Comment: I've now retried all of your revisions if in case they would have worked (without the 2 rewrite rules I missed to remove), but they currently are working the same way as it is now. The only faulty one is the index. Removing this `RewriteRule ^cover/(.*)-(.*)/?$ index.php?id=$2&title=$1 [NC,L]` would mean the page/url not working, but leaving it in would mean that the URL leads to the correct page initially, but when navigation is used, the results do not update, & when navigation is used twice, it appends the pagination variables to the existing URL.

Comment: `when navigation is used twice`: Problem is use of relative URL on your side. Make sure to use absolute URLs, Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: Navigation URL actually is an absolute path: `http://` `site.com/search.php?tag=KEYPHRASE&page=2`... (I just had to break it up coz it doesn't let me post a link/URL in full) I have no problem with the SEARCH URL anymore, & navigation functions internally on the page, as well. The only thing that doesn't work for me is the index... & I can't figure out why the search page is working, while the index doesn't cooperate. This is becoming so frustrating. I appreciate all your help & patience on this, you seem to be getting it more than I am. I'm just lost at this point.

Comment: What is exact URL do you see for index page when pagination doesn't work? Also tell what should be exact "internal URL" for index page with pagination.

Comment: It's ok, I decided to remove pagination for the index, & replaced it with a "Continue to browse" link instead, that leads to a page with pagination enabled. Thanks for your help!